# Как переместить элемент

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть некий тест, после прохождения необходимо вывести результаты на то место,где были вопросы

[image: Есть некий тест]

[image: После прохождения, результаты появляются не в том месте]

js

```
const url = window.location.href
// console.log(url)
const quizBox = document.getElementById('quiz-box')


$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: `${url}/data`,
    success: function (response) {
        // console.log(response)
        const data = response.data
        data.forEach(el => {
            for (const [question, answers] of Object.entries(el)) {
                // console.log(question)
                // console.log(answers)
                quizBox.innerHTML += `
                    <hr>
                    <div class="mb-2">
                        <b>${question}</b>
                    </div>
                `
                answers.forEach(answer => {
                    quizBox.innerHTML += `
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" class="ans" id="${question} - ${answer}" name="${question}" value="${answer}">
                        <label for="${question}">${answer}</label>
                    </div>
                    `;
                });
                console.log('test');
            }
        });
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    },
})

const quizForm = document.getElementById('quiz-form')

const sendData = () => {
    const csrf = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]')
    const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.ans')]
    const data = {}
    data['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = csrf.value

    console.log(elements)
    elements.forEach(el => {
        if (el.checked) {
            data[el.name] = el.value
        } else {
            if (!data[el.name]) {
                data[el.name] = null
            }
        }
    })

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: `${url}/save/`,
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            // console.log(response)
            // console.log(data)
            const results = response.results
            console.log(results)

            quizForm.classList.add('invisible')

            // const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
            // para.innerHTML = someHere;

            results.forEach(res => {
                const resDiv = document.createElement("div")
                for (const [question, resp] of Object.entries(res)) {
                    //     console.log(question)
                    //     console.log(resp)
                    //     console.log('******')

                    resDiv.innerHTML += question
                    const cls = ['container', 'p-3', 'text-light', 'h5']
                    resDiv.classList.add(...cls)

                    if (resp == 'not answered') {
                        resDiv.innerHTML += ' - not answered'
                        resDiv.classList.add('bg-danger')
                    }
                    else {
                        const answer = resp['answered']
                        const correct = resp['correct_answer']

                        if (answer == correct) {
                            resDiv.classList.add('bg-success')
                            resDiv.innerHTML += `answered: ${answer}`
                        } else {
                            resDiv.classList.add('bg-danger')
                            resDiv.innerHTML += ` | correct answer:  ${correct}`
                            resDiv.innerHTML += ` | your answered:  ${answer}`
                        }
                    }
                }
                const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
                body.append(resDiv)
                // document.getElementById("BODY").appendChild(resDiv);
            })
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
}

quizForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    sendData()
})
```

html

```
{% block content %}
<!-- Название теста -->
<h2>{{obj.name}}</h2>

<form id="quiz-form" class="mt-3 mb-3">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div id="quiz-box"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Сохранить</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: разметка с тестами загружается в #quiz-box. и вы после заполнения отправляете запрос на проверку или типа того. так почему бы после отправки формы не удалить нод с тестами. типа document.getElementById("quiz-box").remove() ну или вообще всю форму взяв ее по ид #quiz-form, раз вы и так в конец body добавляете результаты теста

Comment: Спасибо большое!